# Member not found error

Tags: javascript

Here i have following piece of code in javascript that popup a confirmation alert box wherein there are two button yes and no. On clicking yes it should go to given link but it give member not found error.

```
$.when(confirmationMsg(FINF_CONFIRM_CLEAR)).then(
    function (confirm) {
        if (confirm) {
            frm.action = "associationRuleAnalyser.do?mode=associationRuleStartAnalyser";
            frm.submit();
        }
    });
```

Expected output: On clicking yes it should redirect to the given link

Comment: where `frm` is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what frm is, but you could use the [window.confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) method:

```
function submitdata() { 
  var r = confirm('Confirmation message');
  if (r == true) {
    window.open('http://www.yourpage.com');
  } else {
    alert('never mind');
  }
  return false;         
}
```